# Whats the frequency of the modes in a waveguide?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, dielectric, waveguide

I have been able to confuse myself: I am studying the form of the modes in a rectangular waveguide:
[image]

I understand that each mode has a different spatial distribution, but what I dont understand is if all the modes have the same frequency?

or each spatial distribution has a different frequency?

I hope you can help me
Thank you

Comment: in a longitudinally homogeneous waveguide the mode shapes are frequency independent

Answer (score -1):

Your pictures show square waveguides.  For this case the frequencies are proportional to $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$, where m and n are the number of bumps in each direction.  For your pictures this gives the frequency ratios $1:\sqrt{2}:1:\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}:\sqrt{3}:\sqrt{3}:2$.